# Function doesn't recognize global variable for play/pause slideshow

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a play/pause button for my javascript slideshow, but the button has stalled my progress because of some scope issues. I toggle between two string values by clicking the element `play`. While the function `slideshow` does print out `working`, it fails to print the state out and execute the function.

Here is the fiddle with the gallery:

**[Fiddle live example](https://jsfiddle.net/u9gqct9v/)**

I would really appreciate your help

```
var state='play'
slideshow()

pause.onclick=function(){
    console.log(state)
    if (state=='play')
    {
        state='pause'
    }
    else{
        state='play'
    }
}

function slideshow(){
    console.log('working')
    if (state == 'play'){
        console.log('play')
        var pic='<img src="'+ images[slide]+'">'
            gallery.innerHTML=pic
            slide+=1;
            console.log(slide)
            if(slide-1==length){
                slide=0
            setTimeout(slideshow, 3000); 
            }   
        }
    }
```

Comment: In your fiddle, run `slideshow()` **after** setting `var state='play'`. Your fiddle also doesn't contain any slide object.

Comment: thanks you, I updated the fiddle. Do you know why the slideshow is not running automatically?  https://jsfiddle.net/u9gqct9v/11/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have put a completed fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/u9gqct9v/13/).

Your slideshow wasn't working initially for a couple of reasons:

1. Your check for when the slide counter has reached max was incorrect. It needs to be: `if(slide==images.length){`.
2. You had a `}` in the wrong place. It was only setting the timeout if inside the `if`.

Comment: just to make sure i understand, the call to `slideshow` right before the `function slideshow()` is only called when the script first runs right?

Comment: Yes. Your logic was correct, just a few small mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

**[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u9gqct9v/1/)**.

Please check the console you could see a *not defined* error :

> Uncaught ReferenceError: slide is not defined(…)

And when you declare the slide variable you'll get :

> Uncaught ReferenceError: gallery is not defined(…)

You've to declare the both `slide` and `gallery` variables :

```
var slide=0;
var gallery= document.getElementsByClassName('gallery')[0];
```

Hope this helps.